# Expo-AV not loading audio from server on iOS

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, expo-av

I am building an audio player for my react native expo project. I am using expo-av to play the sound that I am pulling from my AWS s3 bucket. I am using expo SDK 44. Everything works fine on Android, but I am receiving an error on iOS:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: This media format is not supported. - The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11828 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain".]
```

-I have tried this with both .mp3 and .m4a files

-everything works on android

-local files work on iOS (require('./myaudiotrack.mp3') but not from my bucket

-this seems to be a problem with the URL that is being returned from the s3bucket and it is working with a URL with an audio file extension.

```
async function PlayPause() {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            staysActiveInBackground: true,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
            shouldDuckAndroid: false,
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
          });
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            {uri: AudioUri}, <------ this works on android, not ios
            //require('../assets/zelda.mp3'), <--this works
            {
                shouldPlay: true,
                rate: 1.0,
                shouldCorrectPitch: false,
                volume: 1.0,
                isMuted: false,
                isLooping: false,
            },
        );
        setSound(sound);
        await sound.playAsync(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by declaring a file type using `contentType: "audio/mp3"` during the bucket upload.